# C# - SELECT Query number of rows affected is always -1

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code and it always returns -1.I have three tables (a picture is more suggestive ):
[image]

I want to see if the row is already in the ReservationDetails table, and if it's not to insert it.

```
try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection... 
            SqlCommand slct = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ReservationDetails WHERE rID=@rID AND RNumber=@RNumber", conn);
            slct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rID", (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue);
            slct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RNumber", dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);

            int noRows;//counts if we already have the entry in the table
            conn.Open();
            noRows = slct.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("The result of select="+noRows);

            if (noRows ==0)    //we can insert the new row
```

Comment: why are you using `ExecuteNonQuery` for a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: what should i use then?
P.S. it's not a big project so nobody will insert anything :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should

1) Change your TSQL to

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ReservationDetails WHERE ...
```

(better still, use `IF EXISTS` ...)

2) and use [`ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx):

```
noRows = (int) slct.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also: you will need to use a transaction (or some other atomic technique), or else someone could insert a row in-between you testing and trying to insert it...

All that said, it would be better to create a stored procedure that given your parameters, atomically tests and inserts into the table, returning `1` if successful, or `0` if the row already existed.

Answer (score 8):

Have you read the documentation of `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`?

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.** If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

And your query is SELECT.

Comment: ok, but the method's short review says "returns the no. of affected rows" I tought it's something rong in the select

Comment: @nickNatra: How many rows would you expect to be *affected* by a query? A query doesn't *affect* anything - it just queries.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: When I do a SELECT in SQL Server Management, it says "# row(s) affected".

Comment: @K_Rol: I'd say that's the oddity rather than the Java behaviour here :)

Answer (score 2):

It is better to do it in a single query so that you do not need to request server two times.

Create a procedure like this and call it from the code.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from ReservationDetails WHERE rID=@rID AND RNumber=@RNumber)
BEGIN
 insert into ReservationDetails values(@rID,@RNumber)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

As per Microsoft:

`You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for example, querying the structure of a database or creating database objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.`

What you may need, instead of ExecuteNonQuery is ExecuteScalar and put the COUNT in your select query.

i.e.

```
SqlCommand slct = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ReservationDetails WHERE   rID=@rID AND RNumber=@RNumber", conn);
```

Also, try to make use of the using statement in C#, so you don't need to worry about closing the connection manually, even if things fail.

i.e.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        newProdID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Answer (score 1):

@nickNatra

When ever you use

> Select command

It will return you values. Which can be either used by

> DataSet or SqlDataReader

But

> command.ExecuteNonQuery()

is used only when you are using

> Insert , Update , Delete where the **Rows are getting effected in your table**

Yes, If you do want to know how much records are there in your query.
You can perform

> a) Modify your query "select count(*) from *table*"

where you will only get one value ie. Number of Rows.

> b) Using this query perform command. ExecuteScalar() which will return only **First row and first column** which is the **Row Count**

Hence this satisfy's your requirement.

Cheers!!